# Generating a uniform distribution in the volume of a box

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose I have a three dimensional box, of volume $V$, and with lengths $x, y$, and $z$.  I then change the box volume by $\Delta V$, such that $(V + \Delta V) = (x + \Delta x)(y + \Delta y)(z + \Delta z)$.

I would like to generate a uniform distribution of box volumes on some interval, such that $\Delta V \in \left[-\epsilon, \epsilon \right]$.

How should I select $\Delta x, \Delta y$, and $\Delta z$, such that they each follow the same distribution, but generate this uniform distribution in volume?

Answer (score 0):

(This is not an answer.)

Not sure this is possible at all. In the simple case $x=y=z=1$, one looks for some i.i.d. random variables $U$, $V$ and $W$ such that $UVW$ is uniform on $(1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon)$.

Thus, $\sqrt[3]{1-\epsilon}\leqslant U\leqslant\sqrt[3]{1+\epsilon}$ with full probability, and, in terms of generating functions, for every $s$, one should have
$$
E(U^s)=\sqrt[3]{\frac{(1+\epsilon)^{s+1}-(1-\epsilon)^{s+1}}{2(s+1)\epsilon}}.
$$
Considering $T=U/\sqrt[3]{1+\epsilon}$ and $t=(1-\epsilon)/(1+\epsilon)$, one gets $t$ in $(0,1)$, $\sqrt[3]{t}\leqslant T\leqslant1$ with full probability, and, for every $s$,
$$
E(T^s)=\sqrt[3]{\frac{1-t^{s+1}}{(s+1)(1-t)}}.
$$